# Unable to load a specific URL with Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I’m unable to load the following URL with Cypress. Getting timeout error. I have set the page load time to 2 mins, still same issue. General URLs eg. `https://www.google.co.nz/` works fine.

```js
it('First Test', () => {
  cy.visit('https://shop.countdown.co.nz/')
})
```

Comment: Unrelated I guess, but only use regular quotes in code (`'` or `"`)

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to make a [mre] ?

Comment: @Elikill58 They can't, it's node code

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way, not the best, could be improved...

The Countdown site has an aversion to being run in an iframe, but it can be tested in a child window, see custom command here [Cypress using child window](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-using-child-window/)

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('openWindow', (url, features) => {
  const w = Cypress.config('viewportWidth')
  const h = Cypress.config('viewportHeight')
  if (!features) {
    features = `width=${w}, height=${h}`
  }
  console.log('openWindow %s "%s"', url, features)

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (window.top.aut) {
      console.log('window exists already')
      window.top.aut.close()
    }
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
    window.top.aut = window.top.open(url, 'aut', features)

    // letting page enough time to load and set "document.domain = localhost"
    // so we can access it
    setTimeout(() => {
      cy.state('document', window.top.aut.document)
      cy.state('window', window.top.aut)
      resolve()
    }, 10000)
  })
})
```

Can test with that like this

```js
cy.openWindow('https://shop.countdown.co.nz/').then(() => {
  cy.contains('Recipes').click()
  cy.contains('Saved Recipes', {timeout:10000})  // if this is there, have navigated
})
```

I bumped the `setTimeout()` in custom command to 10 seconds, cause this site drags it's feet a bit.

Configuration:

```js
// cypress.json
{
  "baseUrl": "https://shop.countdown.co.nz/",
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 20000       // see below for better way
}
```

[image]

---

**Command timeout error**

Using Gleb's child window command, there's a timeout error that I can't track the source of.

To avoid it I set `"defaultCommandTimeout": 20000` in config, but since it's only needed for the `openWindow` call it's better to remove the global setting and use this instead

```js
cy.then({timeout:20000}, () => {
  cy.openWindow('https://shop.countdown.co.nz/', {}).then(() => {
    cy.contains('Recipes').click()
    cy.contains('Saved Recipes', {timeout:10000})  // if this is there, have navigated
  })
})
```

To check if the long command timeout only applies once, break one of the inner test commands and check that that it times out in the standard 4000 ms.

```js
cy.then({timeout:20000}, () => {
  cy.openWindow('https://shop.countdown.co.nz/', {}).then(() => {
    cy.contains('Will not find this').click()  // Timed out retrying after 4000ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, so what I observed in my case was that the URL was not getting added to the iframe `src` property and hence `cy.visit()` was getting timed out each time.

So, I added the URL manually to the src property of the iframe.
Here's my custom command for reference:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('goto', url => {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const frame = window.top.document.getElementsByClassName('aut-iframe')[0];
      frame.src = url;
      var evt = window.top.document.createEvent('Event');
      evt.initEvent('load', false, false);
      window.dispatchEvent(evt);
      res();
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

Now use `cy.goto('https://yoururl.com')` and you are good to go.

Answer (score -1):

The quotes are wrong. Try the below code:

`it('First Test', ()=>{ cy.visit('https://shop.countdown.co.nz/') })`