# Login in Cypress based test with fedrated login provider (multiple redirects)

Tags: javascript, cypress, auth0, federated-identity

I'm trying to test an app which uses `Auth0` for auth. The `Auth0` account is federated with Azure AD, all logins gets redirect to Azure AD where the user enters its credentials. Because of restrictions that is out of my control we have to follow this flow even in the Cypress based tests, using ROPC is not an option.

The problem I'm having is that when `Auth0` redirects to Azure AD it completely takes over the browser, loosing the Cypress test context. Is there any way this can be avoided or do I have to take care of the login outside of the Cypress tests somehow?

These are the steps that we do in the tests:

1. Navigate to app and click login
2. Gets redirected to Auth0
3. Enter email and submit
4. Gets redirected to Azure AD (the entire window is now Azure AD login page and Cypress can't interact with the page)

Comment: It's possible to switch windows, for example a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71251378/16997707) required testing in a child window - but without the app I'd struggle to give you the pattern.

Comment: Thanks @Fody, it's a bit hacky, but I think it will work!

Comment: Almost, it doesn't seem to work using the electron browser? I can't seem to be able to interact with the page then.