# Rendering iFrame in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

Can anyone help me render the iFrame for the following page in Cypress.

https://testnewpage.digitaldisbursements.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to me that no amount of waiting for the frame to load works for this page. The payment options never appear.

BUT, if you open the address in a new window the logos and payment buttons do appear.

This suggests you could try testing it in a new window - the approach is a little experimental but working.
See [Unable to load a specific URL with Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71251378/16695029) for reference.

Here is a working test.

```js
it('Should render the iframe', {timeout:20_000}, () => {
  cy.visit('http://testnewpage.digitaldisbursements.org/')

  cy.openWindow('http://testnewpage.digitaldisbursements.org/')

  const paymentMethods = [
    {imgSrc: 'virtual_mc3.png', caption: 'GET A PREPAID MASTERCARD'},    
    {imgSrc: 'paypal.png', caption: 'USE PAYPAL'},    
    {imgSrc: 'venmo.png', caption: 'USE VENMO'},    
    {imgSrc: 'zelle.png', caption: 'USE ZELLE'},    
    {imgSrc: 'virtual_mc3.png', caption: 'GET A PREPAID MASTERCARD'},   
  ]

  cy.get('iframe')
    .its('0.contentDocument')
    .find('body')
    .should('exist')
    .and('not.be.null')
    .within($body => {
      cy.get('#payment')
        .find('.MuiGrid-item')
        .each((paymentMethod, i) => {

          cy.wrap(paymentMethod)      // check the logo
            .find('button img')      // 1st button on card
            .should('have.attr', 'src')
            .and('contain', paymentMethods[i].imgSrc)

          cy.wrap(paymentMethod)     // check the button caption
            .find('button').eq(1)   // 2nd button on card
            .should('contain', paymentMethods[i].caption)
         })

    })
})
```

It uses the `cy.openWindow()` developed by Gleb Bahmutov here [Cypress using child window](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-using-child-window) with some adjustments.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('openWindow', (url, features) => {
  const w = Cypress.config('viewportWidth')
  const h = Cypress.config('viewportHeight')
  if (!features) {
    features = `width=${w}, height=${h}`
  }
  console.log('openWindow %s "%s"', url, features)

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (window.top.aut) {
      console.log('window exists already')
      window.top.aut.close()
    }
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
    window.top.aut = window.top.open(url, 'aut', features)

    // letting page enough time to load and set "document.domain = localhost"
    // so we can access it
    setTimeout(() => {
      cy.state('document', window.top.aut.document)
      cy.state('window', window.top.aut)
      resolve()
    }, 10_000)
  })
})
```

Also, some setting needed in `cypress.config.js`

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
    },
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    modifyObstructiveCode: false,
  },
})
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the help! As you mentioned a bit experimental, but this will definitely work in the meantime. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually one more question, how would you go about interacting with a specific button. For example, say I want to click on the PayPal button type?

Comment: Now that you have access to the buttons, you can add more assertions inside the `.each()`. Paypal is index 1, which means something like `if (i === 1) { ... }`. Be aware that  after clicking a button the whole `<iframe>` is likely to change.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to click into the button and as you predicted I'm having trouble inputting a phone number / email into the input field. Could you help with locating the new iframe when you click into a payment button?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to render the link in iframe using Cypress;

```
describe("Render iFrame", () => {
  it("Should render the iframe", () => {
    cy.visit("https://testnewpage.digitaldisbursements.org/");

  //this finds the iframe element
  cy.get("iframe").its("0.contentDocument").should("exist");

  /*
    here you can perform additional assertions on 
    the iframe if needed, for instance, accessing
    elements within the iframe
  */
  cy.get("iframe")
    .its("0.contentDocument")
    .then(cy.wrap)
    .find("#elementId")
    .should("be.visible")
    .click();
  });
});
```

So in the above test, the specified url is visited using `cy.visit`, then `cy.get('iframe')` to locate the iframe element. We then assert the `contentDocument` property of the iframe to ensure that it loaded successfully. The rest of the test is explained in the comment above it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that. I just tried running your example in cypress but it looks like it's still not rendering the iFrame correctly. 

Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: #elementId, but never found it. Queried from:

Comment: If the test is timing out and unable to find the element, it's possible that the iframe content is not fully loaded when Cypress attempts to locate the element. You can ensure this by using the `cy.iframe()` provided by the `cypress-iframe` plugin. How it works is that it waits for the iframe to load before performing the actions inside it.