# Tests aren't run after opening link with cy.visit()

Tags: cypress

Tests aren't run after:

```
cy.visit('http://tembo-urgent-care.web.app/')
```

Cypress just open this page as a browser, so I can interact with it manually. If I try another page, e.g. YouTube - it works fine, my tests are run.
Also, if I put this URL in config file, after I run
npx cypress run after browser selection, I can't even select test to run. It just opens the page as like in browser (like in the video).

What I see right after executing npx cypress open

[image]

I have Windows 11 and MacOS. Both of them have this problem, except Mozilla Firefox and Edge browsers on Windows 11. Cypress v12.17.3.

After running

```
cy.visit('http://tembo-urgent-care.web.app/')
```

the tests should interact with this page.

Script that I've tried to run:

```
describe('template spec', () => {
  it('"Start visit" redirects user to the form page', () => {
    cy.visit('https://tembo-urgent-care.web.app/');
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add a sample test that you are seeing not run after the `cy.visit()` command?

Comment: Yes, I've added my test. It's pretty simple, cos this issue doesn't allow me to proceed with it

Answer (score 1):

Some web pages don't like to be run inside an iframe (which is what Cypress does). This one clearly does not.

There is an experimental custom command given here [Unable to load a specific URL with Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71251378) that allows your test to run in a child window. (Only tested on Chrome).

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('openWindow', (url, features) => {
  const w = Cypress.config('viewportWidth')
  const h = Cypress.config('viewportHeight')
  if (!features) {
    features = `width=${w}, height=${h}`
  }
  console.log('openWindow %s "%s"', url, features)

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (window.top.aut) {
      console.log('window exists already')
      window.top.aut.close()
    }
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
    window.top.aut = window.top.open(url, 'aut', features)

    // letting page enough time to load and set "document.domain = localhost"
    // so we can access it
    setTimeout(() => {
      cy.state('document', window.top.aut.document)
      cy.state('window', window.top.aut)
      resolve()
    }, 10000)
  })
})

it('tests tembo login', () => {
  cy.openWindow('https://tembo-urgent-care.web.app/')
  cy.get('button').click()
  cy.get('input[placeholder="Your full name"]')
    .should('be.visible')
    .type('my patient name')
  cy.get('input[placeholder="Your full name"]')
    .should('have.value', 'my patient name')
})
```

---

Since the application is Vue, and alternative is to use [Vue Component Testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/vue/overview).

This will avoid the problems that Cypress has when opening the full web page.